# Application Menu Items Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, menu, items

I am building a simple app in xcode 3, but don't know how to code the appmenu items. I have a few simple items that need codes - open and print. Close and minimise are done automatically. Can anybody tell me how to programme these items so that they can be actioned in the app?

Answer (score 3):

basically you need to declare you actions/functions as IBActions so you can link them in the Interface Builder.

for example, you declare you functions like:

```
-(IBAction) doSomething:(id)sender{
 //do something code here
}
```

The IBAction is really just a nil, but it tells the Interface builder that this is available for linking. The (id)sender tells XCode which object triggered the action.

Hard to explain without screenshots, but here is a quick tutorial for you:
http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/002-MenuApp.pl